# How do I print a QR Code on an Intermec PM4i printer

Tags: printing, intermec

I have an external service which populates labels on an Intermec Easy Coder PM4i printer using a Text file to send instructions to the printer.

My current text file looks as follows:

```
AN 7
NASC -2
MAG 1,1:PP 98,92:DIR 1:FT "Swiss 721 BT",12,0,100
NI:PT "Sample Date: ";DATE$("F")
PP 98,598:FT "Swiss 721 BT",12,0,138
NI:PT ""
PP 98,450
BT "CODE128"
BM 2
BH 50
BF "Swiss 721 BT",10,0,0,1,1 ON
BF ON
PP 98,550:FT "Swiss 721 BT",8,0,138
PB "C7108411Q1"

PP 750,100
BT "QRCODE"
BM 10
BH 300
BF "Swiss 721 BT",10,0,0,1,1 ON
BF ON
PP 600,225:FT "Century Schoolbook BT",8,0,138
PB "7108411"

PP 98,450:FT "Swiss 721 BT",8,0,138
PT "Project:"
PP 290,450:FT "Swiss 721 BT",8,0,138
PT "Project 1"

PP 98,420:FT "Swiss 721 BT",8,0,138
PT "Contract:"
PP 290,420:FT "Swiss 721 BT",8,0,138
PT "219H,219H-ICC G4D"

PP 98,390:FT "Swiss 721 BT",8,0,138
PT "Customer:"
PP 290,390:FT "Swiss 721 BT",8,0,138
PT "Customer 1"

PP 98,360:FT "Swiss 721 BT",8,0,138
PT "Drawing:"
PP 290,360:FT "Swiss 721 BT",8,0,138
PT "921-7064"

PP 98,330:FT "Swiss 721 BT",8,0,138
PT "Mark:"
PP 290,330:FT "Swiss 721 BT",8,0,138
PT "Test Mark"

PP 98,300:FT "Swiss 721 BT",8,0,138
PT "Item:"
PP 290,300:FT "Swiss 721 BT",8,0,138
PT "102X5.0C H S"

PP 98,270:FT "Swiss 721 BT",8,0,138
PT "Weight:(kg)"
PP 290,270:FT "Swiss 721 BT",8,0,138
PT "1,721.300"

PP 98,80:FT "Swiss 721 BT",8,0,138
PT "Despatch Label"
PP 350,80:FT "Swiss 721 BT",8,0,138
PT "29-Nov-13 09:47"

PP 98,240:FT "Swiss 721 BT",8,0,138
PT "Rev:"
PP 290,240:FT "Swiss 721 BT",8,0,138
PT "Sample Rev"

PP 98,180:FT "Swiss 721 Bold BT",11,0,138
NI:PT "Company Name"
PF
```

And produces the incorrect QR Code, as seen in the image url:
http://www.imageupload.co.uk/images/2014/09/30/DSC0619.jpg

Does anyone have any knowledge on the correct configuration of this Text file

Answer (score 1):

[ Intermec PM4i, Generic/text print driver, USB connection, Notepad printing through Generic/Text pinter driver ]

**edit** Possible solution at the end of this post.

I have the same problem printing QRCode on a label, none of the smartphone qr readers read it, same devices and applications read qrcodes fine created in my Java application (http://zxing.github.io/zxing/). I don't know why but Intermec internal barcode_qrcode generator creates different image from the same input data on all quality 1-4 levels.

BARSET attributes are "barcode name", "large bar ratio(not used)", "narrow bar ratio(not used)", "enlargement 1-128", "barheight 1-500", "security level 1=low, 2=med, 3=quality, 4=high"

```
INPUT ON
NASC 1252
BF OFF
PP 30,520 
PT "My label test"
PP 400,380:AN 7:BARSET "QRCODE",1,1,15,1,4
PB "ABC123"
PF
```

I could not send this through Windows network printing pipe (generic text driver or Intermec print driver), it flashes "font not found" error in printers LCD screen or nothing is received in printer. Then I tried USB and at least could print script from Notepad.

**Edit (possible solution)**
I was reading DirectProtocol programmer's guide but I guess it's missing a very important detail. FingerPrint programmer's guide gave me solution. BARSET attributes are *"barcode name", 1, 1, "mag 1-128", "version 1,2", "quality 1-4"* and **trick was to give version=2 attribute**. All smartphone scanners worked fine I tested unlike version=1 was a fail.

```
INPUT OFF
NASC 1252
BF OFF
FT "Swiss 721 Bold BT",12,0,100 
PP 50,500:PT "Text line goes here"
PP 400,400:AN 7:BARSET "QRCODE",1,1,7,2,4
PB "ABC123 aabbcc....very long text goes here...I mean about 200 chars or more"
PRINTFEED
```